# Repro needed : 'picture' graph field not working for posted links

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, image

I need verification on an error to see if it is just me or a FB bug.
The preview image link of posted links doesnot seems to be working, either by Graph or FQL.

Try this one :
https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola/posts/168694756574160

With the graph explorer, go to 
https://graph.facebook.com/168694756574160
and click on the "picture" link. Does the preview image appears ? I have a blank screen.

I see this behaviour on every posted links I could try.

Thanks for trying this on your side. If it is a FB bug, I will create a bug report!

Answer (score 0):

The `/picture` connection of most objects returns a HTTP 301 redirect to the image's URL on the CDN. This will not work with the Graph API Explorer as it hasn't been coded to respond to the redirect.

The redirect allows you to put (for example) `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture` into an `<img>` tag directly

If you want to retrieve the picture as a string, access `/OBJECT_ID?fields=picture` instead